# Removing whitespace from readin

Tags: python

I'm trying to readin from a dat file, but I'm going crazy, the chars looking like " ' " is still in there, and I cant seem to remove them, what I've tried currently is something like this:

```
import numpy as np


def read_in():
    cities = []
    file = open('cities.dat', "r")
    for line in file:
        for city in line.split():
            city = city.replace("'", "")
            cities.append(city)
    file.close()
    cities = np.array(cities)
    return cities
```

Can someone help me out, how do you remove these signs, replace doesnt seem to fix it.

Comment: How does the file content look like?

Comment: Apostrophes and quotes are not white space.

Comment: how do you remove apostrophes then?

Comment: or how can I fix so I only readin the floats given by my content?

Comment: It is currently looking like:

[['0.4000,' '0.4439;']
 ['0.2439,' '0.1463;']
 ['0.1707,' '0.2293;']
 ['0.2293,' '0.7610;']
 ['0.5171,' '0.9414;']
 ['0.8732,' '0.6536;']
 ['0.6878,' '0.5219;']
 ['0.8488,' '0.3609;']
 ['0.6683,' '0.2536;']
 ['0.6195,' '0.2634;']]

Comment: The `'` are shown to represent that the inner list items are strings. They are not part of the strings itself.

Comment: So I need to convert to a float somehow instead, is that what you are saying?

Comment: If you need floats, yes. Remove the `,` and `;` from the strings, then `float()` can do the conversion.

Comment: Edit your question showing sample input and actual and desired output.  Don't put it in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your original data was, for example, `0.4000, 0.4439;`. You have split your data on whitespace, between the `,` and the `0`, and that has left the punctuation in your strings, like this `['0.4000,' '0.4439;']`. If you are expecting numbers then

```
for line in file:
    city = [float(c.strip(";")) for c in line.split(",")]  
    # split on the comma
    # then strip semicolons
    # then convert to float
    cities.append(city)
```